# Developer Tools Shortcut: Remove

Tags: javascript, html, electron

In my **electron app**

The menu bar has `Toggle Developer Tools`

And the shortcut works.

I need to remove both of these features, on more than one `BrowserWindow`.

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`win.removeMenu();`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winremovemenu-linux-windows) to remove the entire menu bar on linux and windows.

[See the docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window#winremovemenu-linux-windows)